# Can ruby exceptions be handled asynchronously outside of a Thread::handle_interrupt block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rabbitmq

At first glance, I thought the new ruby 2.0 `Thread.handle_interrupt` was going to solve all my asynchronous interrupt problems, but unless I'm mistaken I can't get it to do what I want (my question is at the end and in the title).

From the documentation, I can see how I can avoid receiving interrupts in a certain block, deferring them to another block. Here's an example program:

```
duration = ARGV.shift.to_i

t = Thread.new do
  Thread.handle_interrupt(RuntimeError => :never) do
    5.times { putc '-'; sleep 1 }
    Thread.handle_interrupt(RuntimeError => :immediate) do
      begin
        5.times { putc '+'; sleep 1}
      rescue
        puts "received #{$!}"
      end
    end
  end
end

sleep duration
puts "sending"
t.raise "Ka-boom!"

if t.join(20 + duration).nil?
  raise "thread failed to join"
end
```

When run with argument `2` it outputs something like this:

```
--sending-
--received Ka-boom!
```

That is, the main thread sends a `RuntimeError` to the other thread after two seconds, but that thread doesn't handle it until it gets into the inner `Thread.handle_interrupt` block.

Unfortunately, I don't see how this can help me if I don't know where my thread is getting created, because I can't wrap everything it does in a block. For example, in Rails, what would I wrap the `Thread.handle_interrupt` or `begin...rescue...end` blocks around? And wouldn't this differ depending on what webserver is running?

What I was hoping for is a way to register a handler, like the way `Kernel.trap` works. Namely, I'd like to specify handling code that's context-independent that will handle all exceptions of a certain type:

```
register_handler_for(SomeExceptionClass) do 
 ... # handle the exception
end
```

What precipitated this question was how the RabbitMQ gem, `bunny` sends connection-level errors to the thread that opened the `Bunny::Session` using `Thread#raise`. These exceptions could end up anywhere and all I want to do is log them, flag that the connection is unavailable, and continue on my way.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby provides for this with the ruby [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html)object (not to be confused with an AMQP queue). It would be nice if Bunny required you to create a ruby `Queue` before opening a `Bunny::Session`, and you passed it that Queue object, to which it would send connection-level errors instead of using `Thread#raise` to send it back to where ever.  You could then simply provide your own `Thread` to consume messages through the Queue.

It might be worth looking inside the RabbitMQ gem code to see if you could do this, or asking the maintainers of that gem about it.

In Rails this is not likely to work unless you can establish a server-wide thread to consume from the ruby Queue, which of course would be web server specific.  I don't see how you can do this from within a short-lived object, e.g. code for a Rails view, where the threads are reused but Bunny doesn't know that (or care).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to raise (ha-ha!) a pragmatic workaround. Here be dragons. I'm assuming you're building an application and not a library to be redistributed, if not then don't use this.

You can patch `Thread#raise`, specifically on your session thread instance.

```rb
module AsynchronousExceptions
  @exception_queue = Queue.new

  class << self
    attr_reader :exception_queue
  end

  def raise(*args)
    # We do this dance to capture an actual error instance, because
    # raise may be called with no arguments, a string, 3 arguments,
    # an error, or any object really. We want an actual error.
    # NOTE: This might need to be adjusted for proper stack traces.
    error = begin
      Kernel.raise(*args)
    rescue => error
      error
    end

    AsynchronousExceptions.exception_queue.push(error)
  end
end

session_thread = Thread.current
session_thread.singleton_class.prepend(AsynchronousExceptions)
```

Bear in mind that `exception_queue` is essentially a global. We also patch for everybody, not just the reader loop. Luckily there are few legitimate reasons to do `Thread.raise`, so you might just get away with this safely.